# Eigenvalues of a vector

Tags: matlab, adaptive-filters

I'm trying to calculate (with Matlab) the minimal and maximal Eigenvalues $\lambda_{min}$ and $\lambda_{max}$ of the autocorrelationmatrix $R$ to adjust the stepsize of an adaptive filter.

My input signal $x$ is a vector of colored noise.
And my plan is to do something like

```
lmin = min(eig(xcorr(x)));
lmax = max(eig(xcorr(x)));
```

But it fails becaus 'For standard eigenproblem EIG(A), A must be square.'

I think this is a little bit strange, because in my opinion the output of the autocorrelation is always just a vector.

Please help me to find the point, whether I need to use something else than Matlabs 'eig' function or if it's mathematically not possible to calculate the eigenvalues of a single vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The autocorrelation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation_matrix) is a [Toeplitz symmetric matrix](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/toeplitz.html) that can be formed as:

```
Rxx = toeplitz(xcorr(x));
```

and that should give you a sensible (square) matrix that can be passed to `eig`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. One last question: According to the literature the stability of a standard LMS is given by $0<\mu< \frac{2}{\lambda_{max}}$. Is it necessary to normalize `lmax=max(eig(toeplitz(xcorr(x)))` (and lmin)? If yes what is the right way? Dividing it by `length(x)` or `length(xcorr(x))` which is $2\cdot x -1$.

Comment: I don't believe it is usual to normalize the eigenvalues at all. They are what they are.

Answer (score 1):

[Edited after a rank 1 mistake diagonalized by @Jazzmaniac]

`xcorr` of a vector only yields a vector, on which you should build an  autocovariance matrix [as proposed by @Peter K](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/28180/15892).

If I remember well, the largest eigenvalue roughly grows as the dimension $n$.  The theory for these matrices is beyond my knowledge. You can get more information in [Largest eigenvalues and sample covariance matrices](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~aib29/MScdssrtnWrwck.pdf).

It is common practice to normalize the covariance matrix, to get either biased  (`xcorr(x,'biased')`) or unbiased (`xcorr(x,'unbiased')`) estimators of the covariance matrix.

In my memory for  adaptive filtering, with the symmetry, one takes only half of the autocorrelation to generate the Toepliz matrix: for instance `xc = xcorr(x,'biased')`, then `Rxx = toeplitz(xc(length(x):end))`.

You can follow with profit the derivation and Matlab codes in:

1. Hayes, Monson H., [Statistical Digital Signal Processing and Modeling](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471594318.html), John Wiley & Sons, Inc., 1996, Chapter 9: Adaptive filtering ([with Matlab code](http://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/2183-statistical-digital-signal-processing-and-modeling)),
2. Poularikas, Alexander D. and Ramadan, Zayed M., [Adaptive Filtering Primer with MATLAB](https://www.crcpress.com/Adaptive-Filtering-Primer-with-MATLAB/Poularikas-Ramadan/9780849370434) [(with Matlab code](https://www.crcpress.com/downloads/7043/)).

Comment: Thanks for your responce: using something like rng(1); x = randn(1000,1); gives me lmin = -5.3606e-13 and lmax = 996.1415 and a ratio (lmax/lmin) = -1.8583e+15. This value looks very huge to me. Do you have  know-how to tell me if this are realistic values?

Comment: You can divise the covariance matrix by the number of samples. You should get a max eigenvalue close to 1.

Comment: The matrix $x'\times x$ has a trivial eigenstructure: It has one eigenvector $x$ with eigenvalue $|x|^2$ and an $n$-1 dimensional eigensubspace with eigenvalue 0, where $n$ is the dimension of the vector space. So your code is equivalent to lmin = 0; lmax = sum(abs(x)^2)

Comment: @Jazzmaniacc Yes I am of rank one in stupidity. Correcting..

Comment: @LaurentDuval, the matrix might be rank one, but you're certainly not stupid! ;-) Everyone makes mistakes and I must admit I'm often too pedantic. So sorry in case I was giving you the impression you were stupid!

Comment: Not at all. I undertand I just plugged the standard expectation $E(x x^t )$ without the expectation in the  Matlab code (without trying) and  then focused on the condition number and the  normalization. Lesson learned..